# How to show a byte stream response

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, vbscript, asp-classic

My REST API returns a PDF document in bytes and I need to call that API and show the PDF document on the ASP page for previewing to the user.

I tried

```vb
Response.Write HttpReq.responseBody
```

but it's writing some unreadable text on the page. The `httpReq` is my object through which I am calling the REST API.

Response of REST API:

```cs
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, pdfStream, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/pdf"))
```

Comment: That is because `Response.Write()` writes text in the current `CodePage` back to the browser, if you want to send back binary data use `Response.BinaryWrite()`.

Answer (score 1):

In Classic ASP, `Response.Write()` is used to send textual data back to the browser using the `CodePage` and `Charset` properties defined on the `Response` object *(by default this is inherited from the current Session and by extension the IIS Server Configuration)*.

To send binary data back to the browser use `Response.BinaryWrite()`.

Here is a quick example *(snippet based off you already having the binary from `httpReq.ResponseBody`)*;

```vb
<%
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
'Make sure nothing in the Response buffer.
Call Response.Clear()
'Force the browser to display instead of bringing up the download dialog.
Call Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=somepdf.pdf")
'Write binary from the xhr responses body.
Call Response.BinaryWrite(httpReq.ResponseBody)
%>
```

Ideally, when using a REST API via an XHR *(or any URL for that matter)* you should be checking the `httpReq.Status` to allow you to handle any errors separately to returning the binary, even set a different content-type if there is an error.

You could restructure the above example;

```
<%
'Make sure nothing in the Response buffer.
Call Response.Clear()
'Check we have a valid status returned from the XHR.
If httpReq.Status = 200 Then
  Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
  'Force the browser to display instead of bringing up the download dialog.
  Call Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=somepdf.pdf")
  'Write binary from the xhr responses body.
  Call Response.BinaryWrite(httpReq.ResponseBody)
Else
  'Set Content-Type to HTML and return a relevant error message.
  Response.ContentType = "text/html"
  '...
End If
%>
```

---

- [Content-Disposition:What are the differences between “inline” and “attachment”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1395151/692942)
- [A: ASP Classic, Download big files does not work on certain servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39141269/692942) *(useful tips on chunking your downloads)*

Comment: While using the Response.BinaryWrite() its writing some strange characters in browser, do have a way to convert this Binary stream to pdf file and write it on browser ?
Thanks.

Comment: @PrateekMishra The *"strange characters"* are the textual representation of the binary for some reason, the binary isn't being seen as a valid PDF. Here are a couple of things to try, make sure to call `Response.Clear()` before `Response.BinaryWrite()` to avoid rogue characters being passed to the browser before the binary and make sure the `Response.ContentType` property is set to an appropriate PDF mime-type.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to define the content type of the response as PDF:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
```

Then write the binary data to the response:

```
Response.BinaryWrite(httpReq.ResponseBody)
```

Full example:

```
url = "http://yourURL"

Set httpReq = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
httpReq.Open "GET", url, False
httpReq.Send

If httpReq.Status = "200" Then
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.BinaryWrite(httpReq.ResponseBody)
Else
    ' Display an error message
    Response.Write("Error")
End If
```

Comment: In the full example I would be checking `If httpReq.Status = 200 Then` before returning the binary so any errors can be handled independently, maybe even switch the content-type.

Comment: Thanks, good advice for the response status. For the content-type, I don't think that's needed if the REST API call is supposed to return a binary.

Comment: Technically the `Content-Type` is never needed because the Browser can infer it, doesn't mean you shouldn't set it explicitly though.

Comment: If you have in server headers: `X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff`, the browser will not do a MIME-type sniffing.

Comment: True, not the default on IIS though. But, all the more reason to explicitly set the `Content-Type` header.