# Classic ASP: how to show a PDF that is returned by Json

Tags: json, pdf, asp-classic

I want to let the users download a PDF that is received back from a API after a Json request.
When a user opens ShowPDF.asp the request happens and there opens a new window where the PDF is downloaded.

The problem is that the downloaded PDF is not valid; it says that the file can't be opened. The size of the file is around 500kb, so there is something in it.
When I make the same request in Postman I see the content from the PDF file in the result screen and when I save it it's also around 500kb.

What is received back from the request is the actual content of the PDF file:

```
%PDF-1.4
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
```

The code:

**PDF.asp**

```
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=name.pdf
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"    

PDFcontent = GetPDF(strToken) 
response.write PDFcontent
```

**GetPDF(sToken)**

```
public function GetPDF(sToken)
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    xmlhttp.open "GET", "www.fakeUrl.com/rest/download", false
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer "& sToken         
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8" 
    xmlhttp.send ""
    GetPDF = xmlhttp.responseText
end function
```

**ShowPDF.asp**

```
window.open('PDF.asp');
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems like you should be returning the binary data, not `ResponseText`. Use [`xmlhttp.ResponseBody`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms753682(v=vs.85)) instead and use [`Response.BinaryWrite()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524318%28v%3dvs.90%29) to write the raw binary response.

Comment: Yes, that did it.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are treating the download of a binary file as if it was text. But luckily the fix isn't too difficult.

Adjust the

```
GetPDF = xmlhttp.responseText
```

to

```
GetPDF = xmlhttp.responseBody
```

Then change

```
response.write PDFcontent
```

to

```
Response.BinaryWrite PDFcontent
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Answer to: How to show a byte stream response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42292267/692942)